# excel - change multiple columns to rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to convert a table, below is an example of what I want to achieve.
[I need a way to convert this table]

[image]

[to this]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have already achieved what you are looking to do. Is there anything we can help with?

Comment: You haven't at all explained what you've tried - we can't do the work for you. Try something, be a problem solver. If you get stuck, then come back to us

Comment: Your conversion need multiple steps (get list of unique countries, then get corresponding companies), Where did you get stuck?